# UI tests for CarPlay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, carplay

Is it possible to add UI tests for CarPlay using XCTest framework?

```swift
    func testExample() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
    }
```

This is the basic UI test that I have but it does not launch the extended display for CarPlay.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible yet to automate CarPlay-related tests. Though you still can open a CarPlay interface (by changing simulator settings), and then get the elements tree.